# DataFixtures Symfony 3.3 SQLSTATE[23000]

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fopen, fixtures

*Hi,
I want to generate content from Datafixtures in Symfony 3.3*

If i use the Load method from a csv file i have a  SQLSTATE[23000] error, if i use string data in method it work well but one by one ...is theire no interest

```
<?php


namespace PasswordManager\Bundle\PlatformBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;


use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use PasswordManager\Bundle\PlatformBundle\Entity\Password as Password;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use PasswordManager\Bundle\PlatformBundle\Controller\PasswordController;



class LoadPassword extends PasswordController implements FixtureInterface
{

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager){



        $csv = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/loadexistPass/file.csv', 'r');
        $i = 0;
        while (!feof($csv)) {
            $line = fgetcsv($csv);
            $existantPass[$i] = new Password();
            $existantPass[$i]->setSlug($line[0]);
            $existantPass[$i]->setShared(1);
            $existantPass[$i]->setTitle($line[0]);
            $existantPass[$i]->setUrl($line[0]);
            $existantPass[$i]->setLogin($line[1]);
            $existantPass[$i]->setPassword($line[2]);
            $existantPass[$i]->setContent('my str');
            $manager->persist($existantPass[$i]);




            $i = $i ++;
        }

        fclose($csv);

        $manager->flush();
    }



}
```

My exception :

```
 [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\NotNullConstraintViolationException]             
  An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO password (slug, share  
  d, date, nb_applications, title, url, login, password, content, updated_  
  at, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["-5"  
  , 1, "2018-09-11 16:46:04", 0, null, null, null, null, "my str", null, n  
  ull]:                                                                     
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' can  
  not be null
```

Can you help me?

Column 'title' can  not be null  But when i dump content frym file it display content

Comment: Can you dump the content of line? Looks like $line[0] is empty.

Comment: `Column 'title' can not be null`  Make sure what you're passing in for a title has a value.

Comment: `Column 'title' can  
  not be null ` and you are passing `null` to that parameter

Comment: Hello Gérald, the goal of your fixtures is to run your application in dev environment right? Why do you take your data from a `.csv`? I hope this file doesn't contain reals credentials and isn't versioned ;) Otherwise let me advert you that is very bad/dangerous practice

Comment: dump of $line[0]  display "URL "
"myurl.com"
null

Comment: Hi Mcsky, this instance is only deployed locally and will not be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Message:

```
Column 'title' can not be null 

$existantPass[$i]->setTitle($line[0]?? 'some-value');
```

Comment: dump of $line[0] display "URL " "myurl.com" null                                                   
dump of $line[1] display "URL "
"Account "
"myAccount"
null